# How to remove duplicates lines from text file while keeping order of file

Tags: windows, powershell, text-files

I have a text file with 105,779 lines containing duplicates. I need to remove the duplicates without changing the order. I am able to remove the duplicates, but it is changing the order of the text file. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

The [`Select-Object`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/select-object) cmdlet has a `-Unique` switch that does just what you want:

```
Get-Content allMethods.txt | Select-Object -Unique > uniqueMethods.txt
```

Note (written as of PowerShell 7.2.3):

- While `Select-Object -Unique` is surprisingly slow, it still outperforms [your own manual solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72130625/45375).

  - The inefficient implementation is the subject of [GitHub issue #11221](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/11221).
- Unlike PowerShell in general, `-Unique` is surprisingly and invariably case-*sensitive*:

  ```
  'a', 'a', 'b' | Select-Object -Unique # -> 'a', 'b'

  'a', 'A', 'b' | Select-Object -Unique # !! -> 'a', 'A', 'b'
  ```

  - See [GitHub issue #12059](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/12059) for a discussion of this unexpected behavior. (The expected behavior would be to case-*insensitive* by default and offer a case-sensitive *opt-in*).